# Old Self-Tracking Entities code - how to make a database change in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Self-Tracking Entities code - how to make a small change with visual studio 2015

"Entity Framework" is the preferred solution but 
is there a way to auto generate the Self-Tracking Entities using 
visual studio 2015 ?

Answer for VS 2010 or VS 2012 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613941

This step fails with VS 2015

> Select Online from the left pane and search for STE Generator

Answer (score 0):

**Update the "Self-Tracking Entities code" from the database**

- open a ".edmx" file
- right click on an empty area. From menu select "Update Model from Database"
- add any new tables and run the update
- Did a rebuild (might not be important)
- in "Solution explorer" right click on "SelfTrackingEntities.tt". From menu select "Run Custom Tool" (first .Data, then .DataTransfer)